# Hosting a simple PHP Websocket with Hostinger VPS + CloudPanel + Nginx

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, websocket, ratchet

I have built a chat app that uses **Ratchet** as the websocket library which I want to host online. But before that, I want to test the websocket connection online first so that I can confirm everything is working well before hosting the actual application. For this, I have downloaded two files from Github which is a simple PHP websocket script. One is `index.php` for the client side browser connection and one is `socket.php` which runs the server and connects in the terminal. This both scripts run well in the `Xampp` environment on my PC. I just have to do `php socket.php` and the script runs with ease. However, same method is not working on the VPS when I try it using Putty (SSH Connection). The server is Nginx and VPS control panel is CloudPanel. The two files are uploaded are:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    var host = 'wss://mysite.app:9000/wsapp/';
    var socket = new WebSocket(host);
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = e.data;
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

socket.php

```
$address = 'mysite.app'; // localhost on Xampp and it works well there
$port = 9000;

// Create WebSocket.
$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($server, $address, $port);
socket_listen($server);
$client = socket_accept($server);

echo "Socket Accepted";

// Send WebSocket handshake headers.
$request = socket_read($client, 5000);
preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $request, $matches);

$key = base64_encode(pack(
  'H*',
  sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')
));

$headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";
socket_write($client, $headers, strlen($headers));

echo "Connection Established!";

// Send messages into WebSocket in a loop.
while (true) {
  sleep(1);
  $content = 'Now: ' . time();
  $response = chr(129) . chr(strlen($content)) . $content;
  socket_write($client, $response);
}
```

When I execute `php socket.php` in the command line using SSH (putty), the line `echo "Socket Accepted";` is never executed. Which means the `socket_accept` code is not getting executed here. I have been through several articles and most talk about making changes to the `Nginx.conf` file. However, I am not sure if just making that change will be enough because it can be due to blocked port or something else. Which I don't know how to open or debug. For reference, the code of Nginx.conf is given here:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    {{ssl_certificate_key}}
    {{ssl_certificate}}
    server_name mysite.app;
    return 301 https://www.mysite.app$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    {{ssl_certificate_key}}
    {{ssl_certificate}}
    server_name www.mysite.app www1.mysite.app;
    {{root}}
    
    {{nginx_access_log}}
    {{nginx_error_log}}
    
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
    }
    
    location ~ /.well-known {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
    }
    
    {{settings}}
    
    location / {
        {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout      720;
        proxy_send_timeout         720;
        proxy_read_timeout         720;
        proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
  
    location /wsapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.mysite.app/socket.php;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }
    
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name www.mysite.app www1.mysite.app;
    {{root}}
    
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
    }
    
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I have added this block in the config file above:

```
location /wsapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.mysite.app/socket.php;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Then, I restarted the Nginx server and in the terminal proceeded to the root folder of the website and tried running again `php socket.php` or `php -q socket.php`. However, it still doesn't work. The function `socket_accept` is still never executed. In the browser also, I always get `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mysite.app:9000/wsapp/.`

And lastly, my OS is Ubuntu 22.04. Please let me know if anymore info is needed to diagnose and I shall add it.

**UPDATE**

I want to add this information from terminal that I get by running command `sudo ufw numbered`. These are the ports allowed in firewall.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
9000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9000/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
9000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

I am using port 9000 for socket. But, still doesn't connect. What am I missing? I just can't figure it out and I am stuck on this for days.

Comment: The firewall on your VPS must allow the port. Also it makes sense to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 if multiple network devices are available.

Comment: Where do you intend to point for 127.0.0.1 in the codes? Please clarify.

Comment: `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};`

Comment: That portion is system generated. I am not sure if I should touch that. Apart from this, any concrete solution from your end?

Comment: @RedStarEntertainment: Make a backup of the configuration file, touch it (you can restore later), reload the services and edit in the documentation of your doing and of your findings in the question by editing it and ping back via comments to discuss the new outcomes.

Comment: Tried. Changing 127.0.0.1 didn't cause any issue but at the same time it didn't help.

Comment: What about the firewall? Is the port open?

Comment: Yes, port 9000 is opened for both IN and OUT and I have confirmed that using `sudo ufw status` command. Please check the updated port status in the question.